# Angular 8: How to display dynamically added object in an array at top in Html?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a `formArray` that add/remove object dynamically from it. I have a `*ngFor` to display that formArray.
At the same time I have to patch the stored array to that formArray,
Now if I want to add another object it pushes at last index and displays at last in Html view, I want to display the last added object at top, so how can i do that? I just want to display.

here is the code `ts`

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
  project: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      type: ['', Validators.required],
      date: ['', Validators.required],
      amount: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  ])
})


get projectArray() {
  return this.form.get('project') as FormArray;
}

addProjectArray() {
  this.projectArray.push(
    this.fb.group({
      type: ['', Validators.required],
      date: ['', Validators.required],
      amount: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  );
}

deleteProject(index) {
  this.projectArray.removeAt(index);
}
```

`html`

```html
<div class="" *ngFor="let item of projectArray.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="">Type:</label>
        <select class="" formControlName="type">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="">Date:</label>
        <input class="" type="text" formControlName="date">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="">Amount:</label>
        <input class="" type="text" formControlName="amount">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

here is the func to patch array.

```js
patchProjectArray(pArray) {
  const array = pArray.map(data => {
    return this.fb.group({
      type: data.type,
      date: data.date,
      amount: data.amount,
    })
  })
  const studFormArray: FormArray = this.fb.array(array);
  this.form.setControl('project', studFormArray);
}
```

Now when I add a new array object its get added at the last index and displays also at last, I want to just display the last added object at top. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Insert](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#insert) It will let you add a new AbstractControl at the given index in the array.

**Try this:**

```
addProjectArray() {
  this.projectArray.insert(0,
    this.fb.group({
      type: ['', Validators.required],
      date: ['', Validators.required],
      amount: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  );
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cwsjjy)

Answer (score 1):

In your addProjectArray(), you can put the new item at the top.

So rather than pushing in the array, you can use the array.unshift method.

```
addProjectArray() {
  this.projectArray.unshift(
    this.fb.group({
      type: ['', Validators.required],
      date: ['', Validators.required],
      amount: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  );
}
```